# How to enable smooth scrolling in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

```
I've got my UITextView set up for scrolling like this,

-(void)startAutoScroll
{
    NSLog(@"AutoScroll Started");
    if (scrollingTimer == nil) {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(60.0/1000.0)
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) 
                                                        userInfo:nil 
                                                         repeats:YES];
    }

}

- (void) autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    scrollPoint = self.completeText.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + velocityFactor);
    [self.completeText setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
}
```

How to enable smooth scrolling? thanks

Comment: velocityFactor should be small and  [self.completeText setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];//should be YES

Comment: when I set this to YES the things get worse

Comment: Animated should be NO.  With the update rate you are calling (about 15 FPS) animation will make no difference in smoothness and can cause some unexpected behavior being called that rapidly in succession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the trick scrolling pixel by pixel with animated NO since it doesn't stop like the animated YES property after its done scrolling. The only thing you gotta set is the velocityFactor as the time your NSTimer should be called, not the scroll should move. And after the scroll is done with the contentSize, invalidate the timer and the scroll should stop.

```
- (void) autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.completeText setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.completeText.contentOffset.y + 1.0) animated:NO];
    if (self.completeText.contentOffset.y != self.completeText.contentSize.height - self.completeText.frame.size.height) {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:velocityFactor target:self selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [scrollingTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks) really helped) bright idea, the best way to scroll UITextView smoothly